# How can I keep my css with an overflow hidden which broke it?

Tags: css, overflow

I create a css and it's look like this :

[image: css without overflow]

But when I want to apply an `overflow : hidden` ( in order to have an ellipsis on each word ) it's cancelled my style.

[image: css with overflow]

I create an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cozstm) to show you. I just add a class `overflow` to an `anchor` and I apply an `overflow : hidden`.

I want to know how can I keep my style like the first image and also have an ellipsis on each word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove "position: relative" from - .nav ul li a.

Answer (score 0):

i made this css!
dont apply before and after to a tag!

```
.nav ul li:nth-child(2):before {
z-index: 1;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: -15px;
content: '';
width: 0;
height: 0;
display: block;
border-right: 15px solid #FFFFFF;
border-top: 60px solid transparent;
}

  .nav ul li:nth-last-child(2):after {
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
top: 0;
right: -15px;
content: '';
width: 0;
height: 0;
display: block;
border-left: 15px solid #FFFFFF;
border-bottom: 60px solid transparent;
}
```